# Xen clone vm can't be created

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, xen, lenny

I'm working with Xen 4.0 on a debian Lenny (5.0) .
I wanted to clone a VM , but it seems that i didn't do it well . What i did is the following :

1. Creating the config file of the new VM and setting it up.

   ```
   #cd /etc/xen/vms/
   #cp original.foo.com.cfg copy.foo.com.cfg
   ```
2. Copying virtual disks

   ```
   #cd /dev/mapper/
   #cp -rv vg--xen-original.foo.com--disk vg--xen-copy.foo.com--disk
   #cp -rv vg--xen-original.foo.com--swap vg--xen-copy.foo.com--swap

   #chmod g+w vg--xen-copy.foo.com--*
   #chown root:disk vg--xen-copy.foo.com--*
   ```
3. Symlinks

   ```
   #cd /dev/vg-xen/
   #ln -s ../mapper/vg--xen-copy.foo.com--disk copy.foo.com-disk
   #ln -s ../mapper/vg--xen-copy.foo.com--disk copy.foo.com-disk
   ```
4. Everything is set up, let's create the VM

   ```
   #xm create /ect/xen/vms/copy.foo.com.cfg
   #Using config file "./copy.foo.com.cfg".
   #Error: Device 51714 (vbd) could not be connected.
   #Device /dev/mapper/vg--copy.foo.com--disk is mounted in a guest domain,
   #and so cannot be mounted now.
   ```

Could you please help me sort out that issue ?

All i wanted was to duplicate *original.foo.com*

Thanks

Comment: Hi again, i found the solution

Comment: if you found the solution, post it (creating an "Answer" to your question). [so] is a ressource to learn from question/answers of others, not your private help-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
  #lvcreate -L size -n VM_NAME-disk xen-data
  #lvcreate -L size -n VM_NAME-swap xen-data
```

Then a byte by byte copy

```
  #dd if=/dev/mapper/vg-xen-original.foo.com--disk of=/dev/mapper-vg-xen-copy.foo.com--disk
  #dd if=/dev/mapper/vg-xen-original.foo.com--swap of=/dev/mapper-vg-xen-copy.foo.com--swap
```

Et Voià !!!